# Proper use of headline-elements

Tags: html, semantics

I know that the most top headline must use `<h1>`, sub-headline `<h2>` and so on but my question is whether the `<h1>` and the `<h2>` can be siblings or does the `<h2>`-element always need to be further down the hierarchy than the `<h1>`?

```
<h1>Top Headline</h1>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
<h2>Sub-Headline</h2>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
```

(is this ok?)

or does it need to be like the following for proper use?

```
<div>
    <h1>Top Headline</h1>
    <p>some paragraph</p>
    <div>
        <h2>Subheadline</h2>
        <p>some paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first sample is semantically fine. Read more here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements

Comment: @Ape What do you mean by "proper use"?

Comment: @Ape your first sample is perfectly fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `h2` should never be *inside* an  `h1` (i.e. as a child element) or similar. Your code is basically okay. In general it is expected to use the whole hierarchy, like h3 only after an h2, always starting with an `h1`, not skipping any level etc. It doesn't matter for layout (this can be changed with CSS and classes anyway you want), but especially for accessibility and for SEO.

Addition: DIVs don't count concerning semantics (they have no hierarchical or semantic function), so your second example is equally okay as the first one.

Answer (score 1):

The `h1` and `h2` can totally be siblings. I generally use the h1 for my big headings (usually like page titles or sometimes section titles) and then h2, h3, h4, etc. for the other various hierarchical elements. Both of your examples are perfectly fine and both very common. I don't think there is a right or wrong way to structure your header elements.

Note: I believe header tags do play a slight role in terms of SEO so that may be worth looking into. I don't know enough to really comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

That (your latter example) is not good code at all, but it works at times. It is absolutely pointless to use this. You are much better off doing the following code than the code snippet after this:

```html
<h1>Top Headline</h1>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
<h2>Sub-Headline</h2>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
```

(The bad coding:)

```html
<h1>Top Headline
<p>Some paragraph</p>
<h2>Sub-Headline</h2>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
</h1>
```

As you can see from the above snippet, it is dodgy and doesn't work well. The first `<p>` tag doesn't work, but after you close the `<h2>` tag, the `<p>` tag works fine. Just do it normally is what I'm trying to say!

Answer (score -4):

There is no such rule that you have to write `<h2>` after `<h1>` you can choose any one you like, the size is what matters. If you want large heading then go for the `<h1>`.